# How to express pressure variance in the canonical ensemble of statistical mechanics?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, pressure

The variance of pressure can be written as $<p^2> - <p>^2$. What is another way to express this? I found $\left<(p-<p>)^2\right>=\frac{k_B T^2}{C_v}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)^2_v$ in a paper by Hiura [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10955-018-2134-6).

I also know that in the canonical ensemble pressure can be expressed in terms of A as $P=-\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial V}\right)$ and even as $P = -\frac{\sum \tfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}e^{-\beta(U-TS)}}{\sum e^{-\beta(U-TS)}}$.

However, taking $\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}$ on either of these doesn't yield the desired relation.  In fact,
$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial V} = \frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left[-\frac{\sum \tfrac{\partial U}{\partial V}e^{-\beta(U-TS)}}{\sum e^{-\beta(U-TS)}}\right] = -\frac{\partial }{\partial V}\left[-\frac{\sum \tfrac{\partial A}{\partial V}e^{-\beta A}}{\sum e^{-\beta A}}\right]$$

$$= \frac{\left[\sum\left(\frac{\partial^2A}{\partial V^2}\right)e^{-\beta A}-\sum \beta \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial V}\right)^2e^{-\beta A}\right]\sum e^{-\beta A}}{\left(\sum e^{-\beta A}\right)^2} + \frac{\sum \beta \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial V}\right)e^{-\beta A}\sum \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial V}\right)e^{-\beta A}}{\left(\sum e^{-\beta A}\right)^2}
$$
$$ = \frac{\sum \frac{\partial^2 A}{\partial V^2}e^{-\beta A}}{\sum e^{-\beta A}} = \left<p^2\right>
$$